# How to use grid.show.viewport() function in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridview, graph

How to Plot the below graph using grid.show.viewport() function in R ?

Here is my code:

```
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

a <- viewport(x = 0.6, y = 0.6, 
           width = 1, height = 1, angle = 45)

grid.show.viewport(a)
```

But I am not sure how to convert npc to inches as shown in picture.

I need to plot exactly as shown in picture.

Thank you for your help!

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the unit of `width` and `height` to "inches" explicitly

```r
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

a <- viewport(
  x = 0.6, y = 0.6, 
  width = unit(1, "inches"), height = unit(1, "inches"), 
  angle = 45
)

grid.show.viewport(a)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>